# How to read only a small part of a .XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I built an application in order to read a file, but even with the fact that my connection is fast, the page takes several seconds to load, I would like to know how to read only the first records of this [**.xml**](http://www.cnt.org.br/Paginas/feed.aspx?t=n)

```
string rssURL = "http://www.cnt.org.br/Paginas/feed.aspx?t=n";
System.Net.WebRequest myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(rssURL);
System.Net.WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream rssStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
System.Xml.XmlDocument rssDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
rssDoc.Load(rssStream);
System.Xml.XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
```

Tks..

Comment: You can't request only the end of a web request, it's kind of an all or nothing thing. Does the XML file change every time, or is it static? If it is static you could download it once and reuse that copy.

Comment: I expressed myself badly, I just want the first items, and this file is not static

Comment: *"I just want the first items"* - Something like `rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item[position() < 10]")`, maybe? I recommend to take an hour and learn the basics of XPath.

Comment: Well if the feed is slow to respond, then the feed is slow to respond.  It's more than 5 MB, after all, which is *huge*. There's not a lot you can do on the client side to improve server response time. If the server supports that try including a "send me only the 10 most recent items" URL parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As the fore posters mention you can’t download part of a web request. But you can start parsing Xml before the request finished. Using XmlDocument is the wrong approach for your use case, because it needs the complete request to create the object. Try using XmlTextReader.

Comment: It would be a good idea to implement client side caching, too. Unfortunately the server does not seem to support conditional GET or HEAD requests...

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to download part of a web request and ensure it is what you want. One workaround would be to use the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide).

You'd have to use the [JSON interface](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) since they don't provide a library for C#, but since it's going through Google's servers it will be much faster. You'd have to modify your code a little bit, since it returns JSON by default instead of XML, but that is a trivial change to make. You can also change the parameter `output=xml` to retrieve the XML representation of the data.

Try going to [this page](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.cnt.org.br/Paginas/feed.aspx?t=n), that is your same feed, with fewer elements and loads much faster. That only returns a few elements, but if you want 10 elements, all you have to do is add `num=10` to the URL. For example, [this url](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&q=http://www.cnt.org.br/Paginas/feed.aspx?t=n) has 10 elements. Read the API documentation a little more to see what variables you can add to cater the request to what you want to do.